# Marking Tasks as private

Tags: tasks, restrictionrules

As part of a new implementation, I've got a requirement to allow users to mark Tasks that they create as 'Private' so that other users in the system don't see these when viewing Accounts and Contacts.

On the surface, this appears to be a straight forward requirement but without being able to create Sharing Rules for Tasks/Activities this isn't as straight forward as anticipated. I've already looked at using [Restriction Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_restriction_rule.htm&type=5) and a custom field to allow users to indicate that a Task should be private, but these do not support Formula Fields so this actually hides the record from the Owner as well.

Has anyone solved this before and, if so, how did you achieve this?

NOTE: Judging from the comments on this [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdoxJUAR/more-configurable-restriction-rules-and-clause) I suspect that I may be able to use the Restriction Rules functionality in the future but may need to wait for the next release.